# WordPress CF7 - contact form with double opt in

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a form (CF7, no newsletter) which the user filled out and submit. After that the user should receive a confirmation email with a link. And only after the user confirmed that link the data of the form will be send to the receiver or maybe saved with flamingo.
Is that possible with CF7 and/or maybe Mailchimp Extension?

Comment: Catch the form submission with hooks/filters. On receiving form input just stop and send a mail from your custom code or any plugin say Mail chimp, it should have a unique ID linked to form data submitted by user in temporary item table. When user taps on link just remove entry from table and send it to user or the receiver.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this [Flamingo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/) to integrate contact form 7 with Flamingo. Also can try [Contact Form 7 MailChimp Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-mailchimp-extension/) to integrate with MailChimp. Both have confirmation mail feature.

Comment: Hi @Earid, I installed "flamingo" but I can't find any setting where I can check for "double opt-in". After I submited the form the data of the form are immediately in the flamingo inbox. Can you tell me where I can find docs for this?

Comment: I used MailChimp, double optin option is in MailChimp dashboard, I'm not sure about flamingo.